# Show a div when a mouseover on a link

Tags: javascript

If I mouseover on a link it has to show div.

My problem is that I have to show divs in all of the links inside a page. For each link I have to show a different div.

How to do this using javascript?

Comment: Er...what? I don't really understand what you are asking.

Comment: when i mouseover on a link i have to show a div...for each link i have to show different div in a single page

Answer (score 5):

Since, your question does not specify anything. I will give a simplest solution I can. That is, with plain CSS, no JS needed.

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/N8qah/)

Markup

```
<a href="#">
    Some
    <div class="toshow">
        Hello
    </div>
</a>
<a href="#">
    None
    <div class="toshow">
        Hi
    </div>
</a>
```

CSS

```
.toshow { 
    display:none; 
    position: absolute; 
    background: #f00; 
    width: 200px; 
}
a:hover div.toshow { 
    display:block; 
}
```

You should not try to rely on script as much as possible. This is a very simple example, with displays the use of `:hover` event of the link.

Comment: how to fix the position of the div?

Comment: There are `left`, `right`, `bottom`, `top` in CSS. Why do not you use them?

Answer (score 3):

Steps can be:

1. Make multiple divs all with different id.
2. Give `style="display:none;"` to all div.
3. Make links to show respective div.
4. In onMouseOver of link call js function which changes display property to block of proper div. Ex.:- `document.getElementById("divId").style.display = "block";` And for all other div set display:none; in that js function.

---

**Sample code:-**

Your links:

```
<a href="#" onclick="Changing(1)">Div 1</a>
<a href="#" onclick="Changing(2)">Div 1</a>
```

Your divs:

```
<div id="myDiv1">Div 1</div>
<div id="myDiv2">Div 2</div>
```

JS function:

```
function Changing(i) {
    if(i==1){
        document.getElementById("myDiv1").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("myDiv2").style.display = "none";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("myDiv1").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("myDiv2").style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

If you have more divs then you can use **for loop** in js function instead of **if...else**.

Comment: @HarryJoy What if links are generated dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

look at [jquery each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

```
<div id=div-0" class="sidediv" style="display:none" > Div for first link  </div>
<div id=div-1" class="sidediv" style="display:none"> Div for second link  </div>
<div id=div-2" class="sidediv" style="display:none"> Div for third link  </div>


<a class="linkclass" href=""> Link </a>

<a class="linkclass" href=""> Link </a>

<a class="linkclass" href=""> Link </a>
```

and essentially do something like this

```
$('.linkclass').each(function(i,u) {
    $(this).hover(function() 
    {
     $('#div-'+i).show();

   }, function() {
      $('#div-'+i).hide(); //on mouseout;
   }) 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: oops ...this will need jquery. dont know why I assumed jquery here.

You can give ids to all the links such as

```
<a id="link-1"></a>
<a id="link-2"></a>
<a id="link-3"></a>
```

and so on ..

and similarly to div elements

```
<div id="div-1"></div>
<div id="div-2"></div>
<div id="div-3"></div>
```

and so on ..

then

```
$("a").hover(function () {   //callback function to show on mouseover
    var id = $(this).attr('id').replace("link-", "");
    $("#div-"+id).show();
},
function () { //if you want to hide on mouse out
    var id = $(this).attr('id').replace("link-", "");
    $("#div-"+id).hide();
}
);
```

Comment: if one link is page left & one link is right how to set the position? for each div?